# Is a topological vector space that is $T_0$ already $T_2$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

If $A$ is a topological vector space, then I know that being $T_1$ is equivalent to beeing $T_2$.
Now I was wondering if $A$ is a $T_0$-space, is it then automatically $T_1$ (and therefore $T_2$).
I can't find an easy counterexample making me think that it might be true.

Comment: Why don't you take the field with two elements, viewed as a vector space over itself? And the topology is such that only one of the two points is closed.

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned I am working over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: This is true more generally for topological groups. If $x\neq y$ and $U$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ not containing $y$, then $y-x+U$ contains $y$ but not $x$.

Comment: @korn55 You should add that to the body of your post then.

Comment: @user289143 That would not give a topological vector spaces as multiplication as the addition were not continuous (as Wojowu notes).

Comment: @Wojowu I suggest making your comment into an answer, so that the stackexchange software doesn't treat this question as unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true more generally for arbitrary topological groups. Indeed, suppose $A$ is $T_0$. Given two distinct $x,y$ there is a neighbourhood $U$ of one not containing the other, say $x\in U,y\not\in U$. Then $y+x-U$ is a neighbourhood of $y$ not containing $x$ (my comment above has a typo). Therefore $A$ is $T_1$ which, as you already know, implies $T_2$.